# loop issue with resampling an image 3 times

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop, image-manipulation

I am working on a project at the moment, where I need to resample an uploaded image 3 times, my problem is that if I upload only 1 image, the image only re-samples once, and I am not sure as to where it is only resampling once, below is my code,

```
if(is_array($this->input->post()) && $this->input->post('uploader_count') != "")
    {
        for($i=0; $i < (int)$this->input->post('uploader_count'); $i++)
        {
            //set up the first image manipulation, this goes from source image to a 209 wide image
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = './media/uploads/headshots/'.$_POST['uploader_'.$i.'_name'];
            $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
            $config['new_image'] = './media/uploads/headshots/width_209_'.$_POST['uploader_'.$i.'_name'];
            $config['width'] = 209;

            $this->load->library('image_lib');

            $this->image_lib->clear();
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

            if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
            {   
                echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
            }
            else
            {
                $image = array(
                    'url' => $config['new_image'],
                    'asset_type' => 'image',
                    'asset_size' => 'large',
                    'date_uploaded' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
                    'candidates_candidate_id' => $this->session->userdata('candidates_candidate_id')
                );

                $this->candidates_assets_model->insert($this->security->xss_clean($image));

                //this goes from a 209 image to a 104
                $config2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config2['source_image'] = './media/uploads/headshots/width_209_'.$_POST['uploader_'.$i.'_name'];
                $config2['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
                $config2['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                $config2['new_image'] = './media/uploads/headshots/width_104_'.$_POST['uploader_'.$i.'_name'];
                $config2['width'] = 104;

                $this->image_lib->clear();
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config2);

                if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
                {   
                    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                }
                else
                {
                    $image = array(
                        'url' => $config2['new_image'],
                        'asset_type' => 'image',
                        'asset_size' => 'medium',
                        'date_uploaded' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
                        'candidates_candidate_id' => $this->session->userdata('candidates_candidate_id')
                    );

                    $this->candidates_assets_model->insert($this->security->xss_clean($image));

                    //this goes from a 104 image to 60
                    $config3['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                    $config3['source_image'] = './media/uploads/headshots/width_104_'.$_POST['uploader_'.$i.'_name'];
                    $config3['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
                    $config3['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                    $config3['new_image'] = './media/uploads/headshots/width_60_'.$_POST['uploader_'.$i.'_name'];
                    $config3['width'] = 60;

                    $this->image_lib->clear();
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($config3);

                    if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
                    {   
                        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $image = array(
                            'url' => $config3['new_image'],
                            'asset_type' => 'image',
                            'asset_size' => 'small',
                            'date_uploaded' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
                            'candidates_candidate_id' => $this->session->userdata('candidates_candidate_id')
                        );

                        $this->candidates_assets_model->insert($this->security->xss_clean($image));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this code, see if you still have the problem:

```
if (is_array($this->input->post()) && $this->input->post('uploader_count') != "") {

  // This (probably) only needs to be done once at the beginning
  $this->load->library('image_lib');

  $baseImage = array ( // These options are the same for every resample
    'asset_type' => 'image',
    // Set this once at the beginning, so you get the actual upload time, not the time the resample completed
    'date_uploaded' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
    'candidates_candidate_id' => $this->session->userdata('candidates_candidate_id')
  );

  for ($i = 0; $i < (int) $this->input->post('uploader_count'); $i++) { // Loop uploaded images

    $baseConfig = array ( // These options are the same for every resample
      'image_library' => 'gd2',
      // You can use the original upload as the source for each resample - this will result in better quality
      'source_image' => './media/uploads/headshots/'.$_POST["uploader_{$i}_name"],
      'create_thumb' => FALSE,
      'maintain_ratio' => FALSE
    );

    // Since you are doing the same thing over and over, you can tidy it up with a foreach()
    foreach (array (209=>'large', 104=>'medium', 60=>'small') as $width => $sizeName) {

      // Fetch the base config and set options for this iteration
      $config = $baseConfig;
      $config['new_image'] = "./media/uploads/headshots/width_{$width}_".$_POST["uploader_{$i}_name"];
      $config['width'] = $width;

      // Set up the image manipulation
      $this->image_lib->clear();
      $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

      if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) { // If resize fails, move onto next uploaded image
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        continue 2;
      }

      // Fetch the base image and set options for this iteration
      $image = $baseImage;
      $image['url'] = $config['new_image'];
      $image['asset_size'] = $sizeName;

      // Do the insert for this image data
      $this->candidates_assets_model->insert($this->security->xss_clean($image));

    } // End foreach

  } // End for

} // End if
```